# Properly Configuring Mod Rewrite while using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have found several related issues regarding CodeIgniter and mod-rewrite issues, however, I have yet to find a solution to the issue I am currently having.

I currently have: **mywebsiteurl.netfirms.com/mywebsite/index.php/admin/login**

What I would like to achieve is removing the index.php from the URL like so: **mywebsiteurl.netfirms.com/mywebsite/admin/login**

However, after attempting several fixes I have found here on StackOverflow I eventually stumbled upon a nice little guide written [here](http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/).

I have modified my Mod-Rewrite to look as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
RewriteRule ^(home(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce www
# If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
# the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain) [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce NO www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

###

# Removes access to the system folder by users.
# Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
# previously this would not have been possible.
# 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

```
# Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Even after implementing this mod-rewrite I am getting a 404 error if I attempt to visit mywebsiteurl.netfirms.com/mywebsite/admin/login. If I go to mywebsiteurl.netfirms.com/mywebsite/index.php/admin/login I am able to load the page just fine.

My question boils down to **How do I properly configure my mod rewrite for Code Igniter?** Perhaps I am missing some settings? I'm not familiar enough with mod-rewrite to really know where something is going wrong.

I should also mention that I have made the change in my Code Igniter configure file.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what I may be doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your htaccess file?

Comment: I have my htaccess file inside of the public_html/mywebsite directory which is accessed by mywebsiteurl.netfirms.com/mywebsite/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have my htaccess file inside of the public_html/mywebsite directory which is accessed by mywebsiteurl.netfirms.com/mywebsite/

You'll need to update your rewrite base and one other rule:

```
RewriteBase /
```

needs to be:

```
RewriteBase /mywebsite/
```

And this line

```
RewriteRule ^(home(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
```

needs to be

```
RewriteRule ^(home(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ /mywebsite/ [L,R=301]
```

And this needs to have the leading slash removed:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

so that it's like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

When there are no leading slashes in the rule's target, it's a relative URI-path and uses the base to determine the root. Since you're content is in `mywebsite`, the base needs to reflect that.

Comment: This seems to have fixed the issue. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found a better solution for your problem, and that's very simple.
In CodeIgniter's config file, leave blank index_page and base_url :

```
$config['base_url']   = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

CodeIgniter will figure himself for your base path, and will not use index.php segment in the uri.

Then in your .htaccess file, apply directive to redirect all urls but folders and filenames to your index.php :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will do the job, and you don't have to change anything in any configuration file when you change your project root folder.

Hope that helps.